# How do I detect an all-white/transparent layer in a Photoshop script?

Tags: javascript, transparency, photoshop, layer, trim

I have a Photoshop JavaScript script that loops through all the layers in a PSD file and creates a new PNG file for each layer.

As part of the process, I trim each layer before creating a new PNG file, but there are some layers that are either all-white or all-transparent, thus causing an alert message to be output whenever you try to trim those layers telling you that trimming the layer would cause it to have no width/height (thus causing the trim operation to fail).

I would like to be able to detect any layers that have a width/height, but are all-white/transparent so that I can remove them from the list of layers and not bother processing them at all.

How can I do this in a Photoshop JavaScript script?

Thank you all very much.

Comment: I don't know much about javascript for photoshop, but try [this link](http://www.ps-scripts.com/bb/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=4810) as a starting point.

Comment: Unfortunately, the code in that link was really confusing and made no sense to me, but the good news is that I found a solution. The issue I was having was with the background layer of the documents, so I used the `isBackgroundLayer` property of the layer elements, and I solved my problem. Thanks for the link though.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this video.
https://youtu.be/x_rMhCz-MdQ

There's no direct way. but you can listen to the events.
I ended up doing the following.
set up a listener, recorded the actions
Select -> load selections and there I checked the checkbox for invert

When we get an error and can't detect the boundaries of selected pixels, it means that our layer is not transparent. and vice versa.

```
  selectTransparency();
    try {
      var sBnds = app.activeDocument.selection.bounds;
      alert('This layer have transparency pixels');
    } catch (e) {
      alert('This layer does not have transparency');
      return;
    }
    alert('Transparent pixels have been selected');
  }

  function selectTransparency() {
    var idset = stringIDToTypeID('set');
    var desc311 = new ActionDescriptor();
    var idnull = stringIDToTypeID('null');
    var ref32 = new ActionReference();
    var idchannel = stringIDToTypeID('channel');
    var idselection = stringIDToTypeID('selection');
    ref32.putProperty(idchannel, idselection);
    desc311.putReference(idnull, ref32);
    var idto = stringIDToTypeID('to');
    var ref33 = new ActionReference();
    var idchannel = stringIDToTypeID('channel');
    var idchannel = stringIDToTypeID('channel');
    var idtransparencyEnum = stringIDToTypeID('transparencyEnum');
    ref33.putEnumerated(idchannel, idchannel, idtransparencyEnum);
    desc311.putReference(idto, ref33);
    var idinvert = stringIDToTypeID('invert');
    desc311.putBoolean(idinvert, true);
    executeAction(idset, desc311, DialogModes.NO);
  }
```